# User returns null before loading init state

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

After user authentication, they're redirected to a Home.dart file. In Home's build, there is a bottom navigation bar function which holds the apps pages.
In my home init state, I call a function that loads a user model into a variable:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserData();
    pageController = PageController();
}
```

That way, I can access current user data across all app, without the need to keep reading into firebase, since the model **"User currentUser;"** is loaded when the app runs.

However, for a quick second after logging in, the user returns null when its redirected to the nav bar, due to firebase latency when getUserData is called on my init state.

How can I update my initial page (in that case feed.dart), as soon as currentUser model is loaded? If I switch between screens and back to feed, everything works. I just need the page to re-update instead of having to force the reload.

```
getUserData() async {
    //Loads uidPath with current user id.
    getCurrentUser();
    //Loads currentUser model with current user data.
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(uidPath).get();
    doc = await usersRef.document(uidPath).get();
    currentUser = User.fromDocument(doc);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just convert the getuserdata() to async function
like:

```
getUserData() async {
return await //your code }
```

Or

```
getUserData() async {
UserData = await //response from server
return UserData; }
```

Comment: It already is async/await. The problem is that the initial page after log in (feed) isn't updated after getUserData runs.

Comment: You may try to put an empty setState function after redirection to appbar, it will work but that's not the proper way to solve it, I hope some one can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the await call

```
getUserData() async {
    //Loads uidPath with current user id.
    getCurrentUser();
    //Loads currentUser model with current user data.
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(uidPath).get();
    doc = usersRef.document(uidPath).get();
    currentUser = await User.fromDocument(doc);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for replying and suggesting solutions.
I ended up using the Provider package. I was having some issues with it and that's why I had my code structured like I showed in this question. But overall, I think provider is the best solution for user management, errors like this one are easily solved.
For anyone running into this in the future, check:
https://pub.dev/packages/provider